# How to send image through axis2

Tags: apache-axis

My Service class designed through Axis2, I am able to send any data type of resords like
(premetive datatypes). I don't know how to send Image file.

Answer (score 0):

Have a read of the documentation - its very good for Axis2 -> http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/mtom-guide.html

There are some code examples in there too on how to transfer images using Axis2

Answer (score 0):

Use soap with attachment option or MTOM..Following posts are helpful

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-soapatt/

http://www.keith-chapman.org/2008/09/attachments-mtom-swa-and-base64binary.html